In the (noun) department
This expression or colloquialism seems to have a negative connotation and can be used as an equivalent to expressions with a synonymous meaning.
•   Not too big in the brain department – (meaning-not too bright or clever)
•   It seems to be a bit lacking in the confidence department - (meaning-lacking confidence)
My question is - is this a fixed expression? Can it be expressed by the following formula - in the (noun) department?

My wife's friend said her first husband was lacking in the trouser department. Yes, it's an informal fixed expression, at least in the UK. We could say the converse, that someone was (e.g.) very well supplied in the XXX department.

@MichaelHarvey: One very common (if slightly coarse) example being in the mammary department, for (positive or negative) comments about the size of a woman's breasts.

@MichaelHarvey What does it mean to be lacking in the trouser department? Not being manly enough? Is it synonymous to the idiom - "wear the trousers/pants"?

Saying that a woman 'wears the trousers' (is the dominant partner in the marriage) goes back to the days when women (a) didn't normally wear trousers, and (b) were supposed to obey their husbands. Nothing to do with a man being 'lacking in the trouser department' (though I suppose it might have been seen as a possible result of it!).

@KateBunting Then what is the meaning of this expression - "lacking in the trouser department?

Farlex Free Dictionary has in the trouser department under department.

Merriam-Webster's definitions of department include "a category consisting especially of a measurable activity or attribute" with the example "lacking in the trustworthiness department". You can put in your own measurable activity or attribute; that's the meaning in the question.

I imagine it grew out of the notion of "department stores," in which goods, employees, and shoppers can be "in the ___ department" and concerned with one category at a time.

Beqa - if a woman says a man is lacking or deficient in the trouser department, she may be directly referring to what his trousers contain (e.g. it is small, or reluctant to deploy) or that he deploys it insufficiently often, or in an unsatisfactory manner. It's purely to do with sex, and not anything to do with whether he conforms to some stereotype of 'manliness' in his behaviour, speech, etc.

In very informal contexts, it probably could. The most common uses have to deal with human traits, and there will undoubtedly be exceptions when it just doesn't sound like something you would say. But here are a few made up sentences with random nouns:

She's a little lacking in the common-sense department.
They are light in the talent department.
Instead of saying he was arrogant, I'll be nice and say that he wasn't lacking in the confidence department.

